# yahtzee three of a kind

Tags: java, methods, boolean, if-statement

I am writing a method called isThreeOfAKind() to analyze the values of 5 integers.
This method should return a boolean.
I'm not sure how to put it into code so that it finds out if any 3 out of the 5 integers are equal to each other.

Some background on the program is that it's generating 5 new random numbers at the start which are assigned to integers. For example i have

```
public YahtzeeRoll(){
    int input;
    for (int i=5;i <= 5; i++){
        input = rangen.nextInt(5) + 1;
        die1 = input;
        input = rangen.nextInt(5) + 1;
        die2 = input;
        input = rangen.nextInt(5) + 1;
        die3 = input;
        input = rangen.nextInt(5) + 1;
        die4 = input;
        input = rangen.nextInt(5) + 1;
        die5 = input;
    }
```

The for statement is weird I know but it just makes it loop once (I think) which gives me 5 integers die1,die2,die3,die4, and die5 that have random values between 1 and 5.

My isThreeOfAKind() should somehow find out if three of the those 5 integers are equal to each other.
All I have for that so far is

```
public Boolean isThreeOfAKind(){

}
```

I think maybe an if statement will be used then if it meets the if statements requirements it will return true, then an else statement will return false, but i'm not sure how to go about comparing the 5 integers and then writing the code for it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

OK, a readable solution without arrays, collections, switches and other useful stuff ;) Hope you learn the rest soon!

```
public class YahtzeeRoll {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        YahtzeeRoll app = new YahtzeeRoll();
        System.out.println(app.isThreeOfAKind());
    }

    private boolean isThreeOfAKind() {
        // inspect the dice
        evaluate(die1);
        evaluate(die2);
        evaluate(die3);
        evaluate(die4);
        evaluate(die5);

        // now inspect the results
        if (val1 >= 3) return true;
        if (val2 >= 3) return true;
        if (val3 >= 3) return true;
        if (val4 >= 3) return true;
        if (val5 >= 3) return true;
        if (val6 >= 3) return true;

        return false;
    }

    private void evaluate(int die) {
        if (die == 1) val1++; 
        if (die == 2) val2++; 
        if (die == 3) val3++; 
        if (die == 4) val4++; 
        if (die == 5) val5++; 
        if (die == 6) val6++; 
    }

    int die1, die2, die3, die4, die5;
    int val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6;
    Random rangen = new Random();

    public YahtzeeRoll() {
        int input;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            input = rangen.nextInt(5) + 1;
            die1 = input;
            input = rangen.nextInt(5) + 1;
            die2 = input;
            input = rangen.nextInt(5) + 1;
            die3 = input;
            input = rangen.nextInt(5) + 1;
            die4 = input;
            input = rangen.nextInt(5) + 1;
            die5 = input;
        }
    }

}
```

---

Time to say hello to a new concept: arrays :)

```
public YahtzeeRoll(){
    int input;
    int[] dice = new int[5];  // <- declares and initializes an array
    for (int i=5;i <= 5; i++){
        input = rangen.nextInt(5) + 1;
        dice[i] = input;      // <- set the i'th die value to input
    }
```

Now it's fairly easy to *loop* through the die array and check, if three dice have the same value (one approach: create another int array of dimension 6 that represents the possible values, check the dice and increment the corresponding value in the other array. Then check if any of the other array's values greater or equal to three.

Comment: Ah I forgot to add in to my original post, We haven't learned arrays in class yet and I don't think he'll accept it if we use arrays :( any help without using an array? Thanks for your quick response though!

Comment: No arrays? Hmmm. And no collections, right? Switch-case already allowed?

Comment: No collections, no switches.. If I did end up using that array (which I think I may have to) would I make that for loop go round 5 times instead of just once? or will it get me 5 different randomized integers as is?

Comment: And, please, don't tell me that you're not allowed to pass parameters to methods :D

Comment: To your question: you'll use one loop that inits the *five* dice so it will loop *five* times. `die1` now is `dice[0]` (arrays are zero-based!) (ah, thanks, your loop was not correct. I edited my answer, i counts from 0 to 4)

Comment: Alright, my assignment isn't due until midnight tomorrow so I'll ask my teacher if he allows use of arrays or if I have to use the other way of doing it. Thanks so much for your help Andreas, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If you make a `String` out of your 5 dice, for instance `"25326"`, you can use `StringUtils` to count the number of occurences of each number;

```
int ones = StringUtils.countMatches(diceString, "1");
int twos = StringUtils.countMatches(diceString, "2");
int threes = StringUtils.countMatches(diceString, "3");
int fours = StringUtils.countMatches(diceString, "4");
int fives = StringUtils.countMatches(diceString, "5");
int sixes = StringUtils.countMatches(diceString, "6");
```

If any of these is 3, you have three of a kind

```
return ones==3 || twos==3 || threes==3 || fours==3 || fives==3 || sixes==3;
```

Answer (score 0):

its very simple

```
public Boolean isThreeOfAKind(){

    int input;
    int[] dice = new int[5];  // <- declares and initializes an array
    for (int i=5;i <= 5; i++){
        input = rangen.nextInt(5) + 1;
        dice[i] = input;      // <- set the i'th die value to input
    }
     java.util.Arrays.sort(dice); //sort the array
     for(int i=0;i<dice.length-3;i++)
     {
       if(dice[i]==dice[i+1] ? dice[i+1]==dice[i+2] : false)
        {
           return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
}
```

in short sort the array and look for 3 continuous integers

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int[] rollDice(int[] die) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    die[0] = 1 + rand.nextInt(6);
    die[1] = 1 + rand.nextInt(6);
    die[2] = 1 + rand.nextInt(6);
    die[3] = 1 + rand.nextInt(6);
    die[4] = 1 + rand.nextInt(6);
    Arrays.sort(die);

    return die;
}

private static boolean isThreeOfAKind() {
    int[] die = new int[5];
    rollDice(die);

    return die[0] == die[2] || die[1] == die[3] || die[2] == die[4];

}
```